# Paste syntax highlighted code from Komodo?

Tags: copy-paste, komodo

I recently switched from using Vim in Puttytray on WindowsXP to Komodo on OSX.  One of the features I miss is Puttytray used to let you copy the colored text out of whatever is in your terminal and paste it as rich text on any application that accepts it (like your instant messanger). This makes it easier for me to discuss code with coworkers.

Is it possible to do similar with Komodo?

Answer (score 2):

in the menu you will find under **File / Print selected text to HTML**. At that point you will have an html with the syntax coloring that maybe would be easier to copy somewhere.